# How to send msg between iPhone app and WatchKit app?

Tags: iphone, ios8, watchkit, apple-watch

I am newer one for Apple Watch development. 
Can you please provide me about how to communicate from iPhone app to Watch app and from Watch app to iPhone app ?

As I can see, there is a notification controller which is related Apple Push notification. I would like to connect to Watch app directly via Bluetooth or something. For example, As soon as iPhone app sends a MGS to Watch app, the watch app shows this MSG without any delay.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to communicate with the iPhone app from your Watch extension you can use [`openParentApplication(_:reply:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) since Beta 2.

For the other way around I have been putting a file into the shared app group folder and monitor it from the Watch extension. If the iPhone app modifies the file the Watch extension will be notified and can act on it.